# Filter out second drop-down based on first selection.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want the `second dropdown` not to contain the `first` selection. If i select `"Team1"` in first dropdown, the second one should not contain `"Team1" and to contain the other ones.` The same to happen vice-versa too.

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <select ng-model="name" ng-options="f.name for f in devices"></select>
    <select ng-model="name" ng-options="f.name for f in devices 
               | filter:{id:name.id }" id="{{formEach.id}}">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is a fiddle which address the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/x40ese02/

Answer (score 0):

Change your filter to `filter:{id:'!' + name.id}`.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.devices = [{
        id: "X000",
        name: 'Team 1',
        icon: 'ion-document-text',
        status: 'Owner',
        color: 'brown'
    }, {
        id: "X002",
        name: 'Team 2',
        icon: 'ion-document-text',
        status: 'Owner',
        color: 'yellow'
    }, {
        id: "X003",
        name: 'Team 3',
        icon: 'ion-document-text',
        status: 'Owner',
        color: 'black'
    }];   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <select ng-model="name" ng-options="f.name for f in devices"></select>
    <select ng-model="name2" ng-options="f.name for f in devices | filter:{id: '!' + name.id }" id="{{formEach.id}}">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why is there a blank in second option? on changing the second one... it should reflect in first one too.

Comment: You have both ng-model defined with the same identifier `name`.  I've changed the snippit.